# Android Crop Image with unspecified size

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, crop

I found quite a few threads on that topic, but unfortunately none with an answer for this problem. I want to crop an image with an unspecified size and finally save to new Image.

What I do at the moment (for better viewing I left out the try/catch etc):

```
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 360);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 360);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

I don't know if the user wants a quadrat 360x360 or maybe a rectangle 1024x768 etc. Is there any possibility to not specify outputx/Y with a fixed value?

Comment: Did you find a way to get it working with unspecified size and aspect ratio?

Comment: non yet unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this library to crop image instead.

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

Code from github source

```
// create explicit intent
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);

// tell CropImage activity to look for image to crop 
String filePath = ...;
intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, filePath);

// allow CropImage activity to rescale image
intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

// if the aspect ratio is fixed to ratio 3/2
intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 3);
intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 2);

// start activity CropImage with certain request code and listen
// for result
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
```

Comment: just one question, is it possible to not set a fixed ratio?

I'd like to let the user decide how big the image should be

Comment: try commenting the lines where you set the aspect ratio value as intent extra.. see if it works

Comment: I tried that, but got a nullpointer. Seems like there's also with this crop Image function there's no way to really let the user crop an image with undefined size

Comment: will check source and see if can find a solution